# Cleaning up an old post of mine -- a moral dilemma

Tags: discussion, editing, bumping

I am aware that  math.se and other se sites are intended so that people who google questions can find answers to them on this site so they don't have to actually ask the question themselves. Thus, I often find when I look at my old posts that I want to streamline them, whether that be making what I'm asking for more clear or getting rid of "progress edits" and such.

However, at the same time, doing edits like this will bump the question up to the front page of math.se, and I don't want to inconvenience people who have already seen the question and come back expecting new content. On that same note, I don't want to be accused of superfluous editing just to bump my question. It's a bit of a moral dilemma.

What do you suggest that I do in this situation?

Comment: Note the [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex edits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers), which can assist you in extensively streamlining an Answer with a minimal number of Edit bumps.  Your diligence is appreciated in wanting to revisit old posts.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> I don't want to be accused of superfluous editing just to bump my question.

Well, I think you hit the nail on the head there. It's fine to update and improve old questions (and answers) as long as you don't do so *superfluously*.  Provided that you don't update ten questions at a time, and your updates are meaningful, I doubt your edits will attract any negative attention.